How to assign a point value to value in multiple rows and ranges
I'm cracking my head over the correct/working formula to assign the point values(AE) to the values in Column F to be shown in G.
The correct results to be

106 -> 100
80 -> 75
20 -> 25
30 -> 25
Tried already IFS with nested INBETWEEN, XLOOKUP, AND ...nothing did the job.
I can't be that complicated but I can't untie the knot.
Any help is much appreciated!

Table Screenshot

To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas (instead of winging it from screenshots), the recommended method is creating a markdown table. Use this table generator to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Another way is to share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker to ease the process of sharing

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


You may try:
=xlookup(F4,AD:AD,AE:AE,,1)

